# How to connect message-driven bean to WebSphere MQ queue without activation specification or listener port

Tags: deployment, ejb, websphere-8, message-driven-bean

My message-driven bean:

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destination",     propertyValue = "jms/mytestqueue"), @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
    })
public class MessageQueueInputBean implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
```

is located in a web application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Test WebApp</display-name>
```

My goal is to connect the MDB to a MQ queue and a MQ connection factory. However, in this constellation I only got the dreaded message

> REQUIRED_BINDING_NOT_FOUND for MDB

when deploying it on a WebSphere 8.5.5.

Therefore I created file `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`, which causes the deployment to succeed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <message-driven name="MessageQueueGuidewireBatchInputBean">
        <jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name="jms/myTestActivationSpecification" />
    </message-driven>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

Apparently this configuration only allows `jca-adapter`, which refers to an "activation specification" in the WAS, or a listener port.

My problem is that as far as I know, in the target system (maintained by people from a different company) there is no activation specification. There is a queue and a connection factory instead.

**Is it possible to deploy the MDB referring to queue and connection factory only?**

Comment: I didn't read through every detail, but keep in mind, you're not just connecting to an endpoint.  You're also hooking into a thread pool the threads of which will be used to dispatch your MDBs (with all the normal qualities of service and APIs available).      That's why you need the extra construct of the activation spec or listener port.

Comment: If the target system is WebSphere, then you will always have activation specifications and/or listener ports. It is configured via admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You're not just connecting to an endpoint. You're also hooking into a thread pool, the threads of which will be used to dispatch your MDBs (with all the normal qualities of service and APIs available). That's why you need the extra construct of the activation spec or listener port.

Comment: Thx for your information, Scott. We'll go for an Activation Spec.